# Get current Highest hit post ID from google analytic or Parsely

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics-api

Is there any way that I can get today's top post's IDs from google analytic or from Parsely API.
I want to show it under "Todays Most Viewed" section of my news website. It shows top 5, posts which where viewed most.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using parsely:

```
/*
    Function to return latest post, which are retrived from Parse.ly's API
*/  
    public static function get_most_viewed_homepage_articles ($limit=6) {  
        $attr= array('apikey' => "YOUR_API_KEY",
                 "secret" => "YOUR_API_SECRET",
                 "page"   => "1",
                 "limit"  => "$limit",
                 "time"   =>"5m"); 
        $url="https://api.parsely.com/v2/realtime/posts";
        $url.="?";
        reset($attr);
        while(list($attr_key, $attr_val) = each($attr)){$url.=$attr_key."=".$attr_val."&";}
        $result = @file_get_contents($url); 
        $result_json = json_decode($result, true);      
        return $result_json;        
    }
```

This worked for me. I used it on function.php